# How to get correct value with useState() in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

I need to draw a filled star when item is in favourite. But now I have always blank star in the beginning (even if checkFav returns true).

Example: itemId is 5
checkFav returns true in its calling in isFav useState
in jsx element isFav false

Result: not filled star, but on every click it changes correctly (so its adding and deleting to favourite list)

```
function CardPage() {
    const { itemId } = useParams();
    const [beer, setBeer] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const result = await axios(`https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers/${itemId}`)
            setBeer(result.data[0])
        }
        fetchData();
    }, [itemId])

    const checkFav = () => {
        const icons = store.getState().favourite
        for (let i = 0; i < icons.length; i++) {
            if (icons[i].id === itemId) {
                return true                             //thats returning true
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    const [isFav, setIsFav] = useState(checkFav())

    const toggleFav = () =>{
        if (isFav === false) {
            setIsFav(true)
        } else {
            setIsFav(false)
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="cardPage">
            <img src={beer.image_url} alt={beer.name} className="cardPage__image" />
            <div className="cardPage__content">
                <div className="cardPage__favourite" onClick={toggleFav}>
                    {isFav ? <i className={`pi pi-star-fill cardPage__star`} /> : //thats drawing like false
                       <i className={`pi pi-star cardPage__star`} />}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default CardPage
```

Comment: can you add some console logs for const icons = store.getState().favourite and add the return in answer?

Comment: The question is missing a lot of contexts to understand what might be happening. 
Can you try logging `isFav` into console inside `useEffect` with `isFav` as a part of dependency array and tell what's the last value you see in the console for the same.

Comment: @sid it returns array of favourites: [{id: 1, ...}, {id: 4, ...}]

Comment: does it ever show undefined, null before that?

Comment: @AtulBhatt its returning false for first render. After every click it changes for opposite

Comment: @sid no, it did when instead of  icons[i].id === itemId was icons[i].id === beer.id but I decided there could be some mistakes with fetching API

Comment: seems to be getting interesting.. lets solve together https://meet.google.com/utw-ijnm-uwb

Comment: @ivan239 I would suggest you put your state variable value as an object like below: `{status:false}` and then when toggling it you can do like: `setIsFav((prev)=> {status: !prev.status}`

and then use this value to do a conditional rendering.

Comment: @sid I would also like to join the google meet to see the issue getting solved if you don't mind.

Comment: sure! please join

Comment: @AtulBhatt the main problem was when I had beer.id instead of itemId because of some features of axios working. The real problem now was just in that fact that I didn't add toString() in if, only in console.log

Comment: @ivan239 So I assume your problem is solved finally. :)

Answer (score 0):

useState in ReactJS is asynchronous, thus it takes certain milli seconds to update before which the component would have already been rendered.
One approach I found working was to directly use the value returned from the methods rather than setState.

```
<div className="cardPage__favourite" onClick={toggleFav}>
   {checkFav() ? <i className={`pi pi-star-fill cardPage__star`} /> :
    <i className={`pi pi-star cardPage__star`} />}
</div>
```

Also once you set the isFav using setIsFav, you can use its value in other methods using the state variable isFav.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (icons[i].id.toString() === itemId) {
```

Converting the `id` to `toString()` will help you solve your query since you're also checking for type using `===`.